# Gradle custom task action order

Tags: gradle, task

I'm looking at a simple example of a custom task in a Gradle build file from Mastering Gradle by Mainak Mitra (page 70). The build script is:

```
println "Working on custom task in build script"

class SampleTask extends DefaultTask {
    String systemName = "DefaultMachineName"
    String systemGroup = "DefaultSystemGroup"
    @TaskAction
    def action1() {
      println "System Name is "+systemName+" and group is "+systemGroup 
    }
    @TaskAction
    def action2() {
      println 'Adding multiple actions for refactoring'
    }

}

task hello(type: SampleTask)
hello {
    systemName='MyDevelopmentMachine'
    systemGroup='Development'
}

hello.doFirst {println "Executing first statement "} 
hello.doLast {println "Executing last statement "}
```

If I run the build script with gradle -q :hello, the output is:

```
Executing first statement 
System Name is MyDevelopmentMachine and group is Development
Adding multiple actions for refactoring
Executing last statement
```

As expected with the doFirst method excecuting first, the two custom actions executing in the order in which they were defined, then the doLast action executing. If I comment out the lines adding the doFirst and doLast actions, the output is:

```
Adding multiple actions for refactoring
System Name is MyDevelopmentMachine and group is Development
```

The custom actions are now executing in the reverse order in which they are defined. I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 5):

I think it's simply a case that the ordering is not deterministic, and you get different results depending on how you further configure the task.

Why do you want 2 separate @TaskAction methods as opposed to a single one that calls methods in a deterministic sequence, though ? I can't think of a particular advantage of doing it that way (I realize it's from a sample given in a book).
Most other samples I find only have a single method

```
@TaskAction 
void execute() {...}
```

which I think makes more sense and be more predictable.

Comment: I don't necessarily want 2 separate @TaskAction methods, I just noticed the example did not seem to obey the rule described in the book.

Answer (score 2):

Patrice M. is correct, the way those methods will be executed is undeterministic.

In detail

**@TaskAction** annotated methods are being processed by [AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/project/taskfactory/AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java).

But first Task action methods are fetched with [DefaultTaskClassInfoStore](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/project/taskfactory/DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java) and results stored in **TaskClassInfo**.

You can see that [Class.getDeclaredMethods()](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/project/taskfactory/DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java#L62) is being used to fetch all methods to check if they contain @TaskAction annotation

And here the definition of [public Method[] getDeclaredMethods() throws SecurityException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethods--)

Description contains following note:

> The elements in the returned array are not sorted and are not in any
> particular order.

Link to [Gradle discussion forum with the topic about @TaskAction](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/create-gradle-plugin-taskaction/8538/4?u=rivancic)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't guarantee the order.

For your information, just added one more link which was an issue I raised few years ago, it should be giving warnings or replaced with some other better solutions by Gradle.

https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/8118